# Each Row in gridview as Jquery Accordion control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view where it contains big rows, So I want users to view only one row at a time. for that I thought of implementing the `Jquery Accordion control`.
 I coded the grid control like this

```
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
    <div id="divItems" runat="server">
        <h3>
            <a href="#">
                <asp:Label ID="lblMemberNameHeader" runat="server">
                </asp:Label></a></h3>
        <div>
            <div id="dvROApplicantSection">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ItemTemplate>
```

and

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
  $("[id$=divItems]").accordion();
  }
```

The style of accordion is rendered, but the functionality is not working.
I am not able to collapse any of the rows.

Please do help me what I am missing out here.

Thanks and appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

The Accordian control would require a single parent for all elements that you need to expand/collapse. When you use the `ItemTemplate` of `GridView`, it will be rendered in separate `TD`. I think you should use the `Repeater` control instead. Read details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163780.aspx)

The `Repeater` will allow more control over what is rendered instead of rendering a tabular output as in the case of `GridView`.